# Added effect issue with spark list item redereres

Tags: list, flex4.5, itemrenderer, effect

I have a list that is mediated by a view mediator, so the data provider is managed by the said mediator (meaning it just calls viewComponent.list.dataProvider.addItemAt([object], 0) when new items are added to the list.

The list has a custom item renderer which has an addedEffect property (a basic fade in effect), which of course is supposed to play every time a new item is added to the list.

The issue is that the first time I add an item it works, but for any subsequent added items, it does not. Does anyone know the cause of this issue, or more preferably a fix?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: After more searching, the solution seems to be setting the `useVirtualLayout` property of the list to `false`. I'm trying to understand what is the reason for this, so if anyone has more information, please share the knowledge :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is that when useVirtualLayout is true, only a single item renderer is ever created.  Multiple rows are accomplished by changing the itemRenderer's data, validating the component then taking a bitmap snapshot of it.  Thus the item renderer is only ever added to the display list once, and the added event in turn is only ever fired once.  Turning off useVirtualLayout forces the list to create new instances for each row in the list, so separate added events are dispatched.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. After a bit of searching around, that appears to be the explanation. Thanks a lot!